# JNI: Invoking CallVoidMethod from thread crashes

Tags: multithreading, java-native-interface

For some reason, when I try to access a java object (which persists throughout the entire program, BTW) from a thread, the program crashes. Here's a boiled down example to demonstrate the problem:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <pthread.h>
pthread_t thread;
jobject object;
JavaVM* jvm;
/*
    Our thread function:
*/
void* run( void* );
extern "C" void Java_com_Program_Initialize( JNIEnv* jnv, jobject caller )
{
    object = caller;
    jnv->GetJavaVM( &jvm );
/*
    Before launching our thread, this works just fine:
*/  
    jnv->CallVoidMethod( object, jnv->GetMethodID( jnv->GetObjectClass( object ), "foo", "()V" ) );
    pthread_create( &thread, NULL, run, NULL );
}
void* run( void* )
{
    JNIEnv* jnv;
    jvm->AttachCurrentThread( &jnv, NULL );
/*
    Within the context of our thread however, this crashes:
*/  
    jnv->CallVoidMethod( object, jnv->GetMethodID( jnv->GetObjectClass( object ), "foo", "()V" ) );     
    jvm->DetachCurrentThread( );
    return NULL;
}
```

Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the problem seemed to be a missing NewGlobalRef call. This version works:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <pthread.h>
pthread_t thread;
jobject object;
JavaVM* jvm;
/*
    Our thread function:
*/
void* run( void* );
extern "C" void Java_com_Program_Initialize( JNIEnv* jnv, jobject caller )
{
    object = jnv->NewGlobalRef( caller );
    jnv->GetJavaVM( &jvm );
    pthread_create( &thread, NULL, run, NULL );
}
void* run( void* )
{
    JNIEnv* jnv;
    jvm->AttachCurrentThread( &jnv, NULL );
    jnv->CallVoidMethod( object, jnv->GetMethodID( jnv->GetObjectClass( object ), "foo", "()V" ) ); 
    jnv->DeleteGlobalRef( object );     
    jvm->DetachCurrentThread( );
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: It would be better to pass the object as the thread parameter rather than via a static.

Comment: Because it is itself thread-safe, for a start. The parameter is available: why *not* use it?

Comment: Sorry, but variable-passing conventions have nothing to do with thread-safety. Anyway, I was just presenting a simplified example for demonstrative purposes; I don't generally advocate using global variables...

Comment: I get next error `cannot initialize a parameter of type 'void **' with an rvalue of type 'JNIEnv **' (aka 'JNIEnv_ **')
    jvm->AttachCurrentThread(&jnv, NULL);`

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest you to try to find a way to post the invocation to main thread.

Since the entire process from "AttachCurrentThread" to "DetachCurrentThread" is not locked, the main thread may re"AttachCurrentThread", in some case, before the "run" finished. Thus there would still be issues.